# AWS EKS - EIA attached on node not reachable by Pod

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-iam, amazon-eks, amazon-vpc

I'm using a standard AWS **EKS** cluster, all cloud based (K8S 1.21) with multiple node groups, one of which uses a Launch Template that defines an Elastic Inference Accelerator attached to the instances (*eia2.medium*) to serve some kind of Tensorflow model.

I've been struggling a lot to make our Deep Learning model working at all while deployed, namely I have a Pod in a Deployment with a Service Account and an EKS IRSA policy attached, that is based on AWS Deep Learning Container for inference model serving based on Tensorflow 1.15.0.

The image used is `763104351884.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/tensorflow-inference-eia:1.15.0-cpu` and when the model is deployed in the cluster, with a node affinity to the proper **EIA-enabled** node, it simply doesn't work when called using `/invocations` endpoint:

```
Using Amazon Elastic Inference Client Library Version: 1.6.3
Number of Elastic Inference Accelerators Available: 1
Elastic Inference Accelerator ID: eia-<id>
Elastic Inference Accelerator Type: eia2.medium
Elastic Inference Accelerator Ordinal: 0

2022-05-11 13:47:17.799145: F external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/ei/session/eia_session.cc:1221] Non-OK-status: SwapExStateWithEI(tmp_inputs, tmp_outputs, tmp_freeze) status: Internal: Failed to get the initial operator whitelist from server.
WARNING:__main__:unexpected tensorflow serving exit (status: 134). restarting.
```

Just as a reference, when using the **CPU-only** image available at `763104351884.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/tensorflow-inference:1.15.0-cpu`, the model serves perfectly in any environment (locally too).

Each EKS node and the Pod itself (via IRSA) has the following policy attached:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elastic-inference:Connect",
                "iam:List*",
                "iam:Get*",
                "ec2:Describe*",
                "ec2:Get*",
                "ec2:ModifyInstanceAttribute"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

as per documentation from AWS itself, also i have created a **VPC Endpoint** for **Elastic Inference** as described by AWS and binded it to the private subnets used by EKS nodes along with a properly configured Security Group which allows **SSH**, **HTTPS** and **8500/8501** TCP ports from any worker node in the VPC CIDR.

Using both the **AWS Reachability Analyzer** and the **IAM Policy Simulator** nothing seems wrong and the networking and permissions seem fine, while also the `EISetupValidator.py` script provided by AWS says the same.

Any clue on what's actually happening here? Am i missing some kind of permissions or networking setup?